# What's the role of a bVI chord preceding a ii V I?

Tags: chord-progressions, functional-harmony, chromatic

I'm talking about the chord progression of The Beach Boys' "Heroes & Villains" outro ("Bridge to Indians").

The progression is the following:

I I7 IV bVI7 I bVI7 ii7 V7 I (C# C#7 F# A7 C# A7 D#m7 G#7 C#)

I've sort of understood now that the first bVI7 functions as a chromatic mediant but I don't understand how the second one relates to the following ii7-V7-I. I see how it creates a nice chromatic line, though. Below I've transcribed the exact notes sung (left side) and squeezed them into one staff (right side).[image: transcribed notes]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest a different path to "understanding". Learn to play this chord progression in all keys, and apply the same harmonic movement trick to other melodies. And don't care about what someone might label it in terms of functional harmony. Do you want to be able to play and handle musical situations, or do you want to be able to talk about it and get accepting pats on the head from a theory authority? :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Yeah, I get your idea. While I can sing these four parts in different keys :D, I was actually hoping to get an inside into the technicality of Brian Wilson‘s vocal arrangements^^.

Answer (score 1):

To me the second A7 does not function the way an A7 might typically function. It is more like a C#o/G resolving downward to the D#m7/F#. The A is more of a non-chord tone which is part of the semi-chromatic ascending line on top. In jazz and pop music it is not uncommon for diminished chords to not just resolve upwards by a semitone as they do in classical music but also sometimes down by a semitone or statically with the same root. This is an example of a downward diminished resolution to a minor 7th chord, G-C#-E to F#-C#-D#.

Comment: Would that diminished chord have any function that can be named? Something like common tone with the 7th of the following ii7?

Comment: @user1079505 Years ago I was taught that a diminished chord resolving down a half step is a functional chord. Maybe not in a traditional classical sense. You hear it all the time in songs like Night and Day and Bewitched Bothered and Bewildered.

Comment: @user1079505 …back when people actually used diminished chords, lol!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy thanks for you answer! Do I interpret correctly, you’re saying it‘s really a diminished chord resolving downwards but the A isn’t really part of the chord but rather just a part of the melody? 

Also, do you agree with my interpretation of the first A7? 

Thanks again.

Comment: Diminished chords often use non-chord tones if they serve the melody or voice leading. There is a hidden answer that I don’t know if you can see but it says the first A7 is a subV of the I6/4. That seems a reasonable explanation to me.  Remember in ANY music not everything has a functional explanation. Analysis is sometimes just an attempt to explain creativity.

Answer (score 0):

It's there for the reason stated: to create a chromatic line. It's not a functional chord so much as a contrapuntal one.

Functional harmony is not designed, however, to analyze popular music, which frequently moves away from the harmonic and voice-leading ideas functional harmony is intended to reflect.

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly. I know functional harmony can't always explain pop progressions, however I've seen it work 99 out of a 100 times. Assuming functional harmony isn't the right tool, which is?

Comment: @PepsiChicken IMO one of the solutions is not feeling a need to "name" every single vertical stack of notes. If we're writing chord symbols for someone to read from, that's another matter, but if the goal is to analyze, I'd just identify the big diatonic milestones (I, IV, I...) and just label things like this "passing motion."

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a Cycle-of-Fifths sequence. The VI-II-V-I acts similarly whether the chords are major, minor, sevenths, or even with chromatic root modification. Thus it's bVI-ii7-V7-I with descending fifths between roots.

Note that in major (or minor) keys, there's a diatonic diminished fifth somewhere (F-B in C or Ab-D in c.) The voice-leading can be made smooth in these patterns (and many more). (Sometimes I call like to call this the ExLax principle; always strive for a smooth movement.)

Root movement by descending fifths is one of the most common patterns; it appears everywhere though sometimes disguised with chromaticisms, passing tones, tritone substitutions, Augmented Sixths, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You‘re saying that A7 replaces a possible A#7 in favor of chromaticism? Interesting!

Comment: Ab can replace A as the root of a progression by fifths A-D-G-C could be Ab-D-G-C with little loss in overall harmonic effect. Richard Franko Goldman's book "Harmony in Western Music" has a good discussion of the subject. (It's not that popular a book, but it's always good to look at amusic theory from more than one point of view. I also like Ratner's harmony book.)